# Component events: list of sObjects

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I have defined a component event like below to carry list of Brokers.

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT">
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Broker__c[]"/>
</aura:event>
```

From the controller method, I am setting the parameter on the event like below:

```
event.setParams({
    "data": component.get('v.selectedBrokers')
});
event.fire();
```

The attribute is defined as below:

```
<aura:attribute name="selectedBrokers" type="Broker__c[]" />
```

But while trying to access the value in parent component, the value is coming as undefined.

```
WARNING: Unsupported [object Object] method: Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive). Returning undefined
[object Object]
```

My question is whether its possible to pass list of sObjects during event propagation.

Comment: `Broker__c[]` is not `Account[]`. I'd expect things to break.

Comment: Hi. That was typo error. I have edited my question. I am not using Account object, only Broker.

Comment: Did you register the event in the component? i see a warning and not an error, would be good to see the complete component/event/controller package to understand how you are passing data to the event attribute

Comment: Please share entire component code so we can see where the problem is

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, Yes, arrays can be passed as event attribute within lightning components framework.

You probably need to look elsewhere for possible cause of error. A good test will be to print the value of list in console logs, before passing them to event.